# Problem in query (PHP MYSQL UTF-8 )

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

After reading the many tips here and elsewhere, I think I have finally made my GET query, PHP and MYSQL all talk utf8.  However, I cannot get a simple query to work where the string I'm matching contains non-ascii characters.  My (simplified) code is:

```
$link = mysql_connect("h", "u", "p") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db", $link) or die(mysql_error($link));
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $link); //connection charset
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['first'], $link);
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, date FROM guestbook WHERE name='%s'", $name);
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
...
}
```

If 'first' is ascii, then the query works, if it contains accented characters it does not.  When I print out the db (in an table generated by php) it looks just fine, as does viewing in it phpadmin.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to tell the '=' operator to use utf8?  Why?

Thanks

abo

Comment: Just because it looks fine, doesn't mean it's fine. What's the collation of the column `name`?

Answer (score 3):

What's the character set of the table itself ?

Also, try running the following query just after connection:

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

Comment: It's not necessary because he uses mysql_set_charset.

Comment: So far as I can tell, everything is utf8. (What's the best way to verify this? Is there a query I can run?). Also the `mysql_set_charset` should do the `SET NAMES UTF8` step.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `guestbook` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<noname>',
 `nname` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<noname>',
 `comments` text NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='simple test table'`

Comment: Are you sure you are sending data as utf8 to the PHP script ? (e.g. did you added a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header or the equivalent meta tag ?)

Comment: Well, if I recall well if your tables used to be latin1 (for example) if you change the table collation to UTF-8, the columns that already exist do not change their collation, it only works for new columns. I think when you set the charset to the MySQL connection, it should take care of this (expect utf8 and internally search in latin1) but it worth trying to create a new clean table UTF8/utf8_general_ci (not utf8_bin), insert few rows and look them up to see if its fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.  I have also done a `mb_check_encoding($name, "UTF-8")` which reported `1`.

Comment: Veseliq - the table has always been utf8.

Comment: do a `select name from guestbook` from a trusted client; e.g. an utf-8 terminal, mysql client, "set names utf8", run the query.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried encoding the name as UTF-8 before the query?

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, date FROM guestbook WHERE name='%s'", utf8_encode($name));
```

If that doesn't do the trick, try `utf8_decode`. It sounds weird but I had weird cases where it did the trick.

Comment: No, that didn't help (either version)